# Translating a Facebook App

Tags: facebook, translation

This post has a great tutorial for using Facebook's inline translation feature to translate your Facebook App into multiple languages:

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2008/07/27/using-the-facebook-translation-engine/

However its out of date, the technique in the post relies on the use of FBML tags which are now deprecated.

What is the correct way to utilize facebook's translation feature now that FBML is deprecated?

Comment: FBML is deprecated, but XFBML is not …

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/